# About making a customize NSString

Tags: ios, nsstring, substring

I have a many strings, here 3 for example:

```
1. example old
14. example new
234. example 45
```

I want to exclude the first numbers and make that:

```
example old
example new
example 45
```

What i do is:

```
   NSString *fixed1 = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, [str length]-3)];
   NSString *fixedStr = [fixed1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@". " withString:@""];
```

And what i got is:

```
example old
 example new
example 45
```

The problem is the space at the start of "example new". I don't know how to remove it, if i try this:

```
 NSString *fixed1 = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, [str length]-3)];
 NSString *fixed2 = [fixed1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@". " withString:@""];
 NSString *fixedStr = [fixed2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

I got this:

```
exampleold
examplenew
example45
```

Im going crazy with this, please someone have a nice & simple idea how to solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
- (NSString *)stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:(NSCharacterSet *)set
```

with `[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]` as a parameter to shave off spaces at the beginning and the end.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (NSString *) customizeString:(NSString *)input {
    NSArray *components = [input componentsSepratedByString:@". "];
    return [components objectAtIndex:1];
}
```

This function works nice if you've the string with same format as you've specified in your question. However put code in `try{...}catch(){}` block for prevent any exception. It just a simple solution but not kneet.